# How to send array by value to function in c?

Tags: c, flexible-array-member

I tried something like :

```
typedef struct vec{
     int sz;
     int v[];
} ff;

int sum(struct vec z){
    int o=0,i;
    for(i=0;i<z.sz;i++)
        o+=z.v[i];
    return o;
}

int main(){
    int test[]={10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    return sum((struct vec)test);
}
```

But this example code can't compile. How to send array by value (not ref throw pointer) to function?

Comment: You will need to specify the exact size of the array, for example `int v[10]` in the definition of `struct vec`.

Comment: of course it will not compile (struct vec)test; you are trying to cast an array to a struct and you can't do that. /You should declare a variable of type struct, initialize it accordingly and pass that to sum(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you will need to specify the exact size of the array in the definition of `struct vec`, for example int v[10]. Also your initialization can be written better. Try this:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 50
struct vec {
   int sz;
   int v[MAX_SIZE];
};

int sum(struct vec z){
  int i, o;
  o = 0;
  for(i=0; i<z.sz; i++) o += z.v[i];
  return o;
}

int main(){
  struct vec test = {10, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}};
  return sum(test);
}
```

Comment: probably yes.
but maybe exist some method(not big switch for evry possible size of vec ,but proc or macro that make uneversal call of function that using some info (like vararg) get info how big getted data?

Answer (score 3):

You can't send an array by value in C. Every time you try to pass an array to a function, you'll pass the pointer to the first value.
To pass an array by value, you can cheat a little and encapsulate it in a struct, and send it by value (so it will be copied)... It's a dirty hack, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4776183/1433392), but well, if you really want that, it works.
Another way is to copy the array inside the function, with the pointer given.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that an array in C has a size, that size can only be accessed through the `sizeof` operator, and then only on the original array. You can't cast an array to a structure in the hopes that the compiler will fill in all fields.

In fact, it's actually *impossible* to pass an array to a function "by value". All arrays *decays to pointers*, so when you pass an array to a function that function receives a pointer. This decay to pointers is also why you can only use the `sizeof` operator on the original array, once it decays to a pointer the compiler have no idea that it's actually pointing to an array, so using the `sizeof` operator (even on something that points to an array) will return the size of the pointer and not what it points to.

In your case, it would be simpler to change your function to take two arguments, the *pointer* to the array and the number of entries in the array:

```
/* `array` is an array containing `elements` number of `int` elements. */
int sum(const int *array, const size_t elements)
{
    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    ...
    printf("Sum = %d\n", sum(test, sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are always passed by reference in C, you can't change that.

What you can do is make a copy of array and pass the new array in the function

Answer (score 0):

As the others noted, the only way in C to pass an array by value is to use a `struct` with a fixed size array. But this is not a good idea, because the array size will be hardcoded into the `struct` definition.

However, you really should not try to pass arrays by value. Instead, what you should do is simply to declare your pointer parameter as `const`, like this:

```
int sum(size_t count, const int* array) {
```

While this does not pass the array by value, it clarifies the intent not to change the array, i. e. you can now treat `sum()` *as if you were passing the array by value*.
If your function does indeed not change the array (like your `sum()` function), using a `const` pointer comes for free, copying the array to pass it by value would just waste time.
If your function really wants to change a private copy, do so explicitely within the function. If the array won't get too large, you can simply allocate it on the stack, like so:

```
int doSomethingWithPrivateCopy(size_t count, const int* array) {
    int mutableCopy[count];
    memcpy(mutableCopy, array, sizeof(mutableCopy));
    //Now do anything you like with the data in mutable copy.
}
```