# How pass(to function) by value variable size array?

Tags: c

First of all I know that array A degrades to pointer when we call function  `f(int a[])` `and f(int *p)` is same.

BUT:

```
1.I really need sending by value all array.
2.I really need that sending size is non const in function (but const size in plase we calling function)
```

I write some example:

http://ideone.com/ZbW0wT

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SZ 15
typedef struct {int a[SZ];} rec;
int main(){
        void pa(rec);
        int value[SZ] ={9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
        pa(*(rec*)value);
        printf("%u %u\n",sizeof(rec),sizeof(value));
        return 0;
}
void
pa(rec b){
        int z;
        for(z=0;z<SZ;z++){
            printf("array[%2d] is %d\n",z,b.a[z]);
        }
}
```

This code work for const size , but how change so pa would get by value some rec which size depend on   passed array?

Update: it must by value sended , but not const sized as in Pascal etc , but in true C way , all pass by value not by pointer on 0 element

and function need universal so user can write func(variablesizeArrayOfT)  where arg passed by value.

if possible need standard way (C11 or better C99 or better C89 or better K&R), if cant then gcc

UPD2: http://ideone.com/H4XGqC
    #include

```
typedef struct{
        int     len;
        int     a[];
} av;

void f(av a){
        while(a.len--){
            printf("array[%2d] is %d\n",a.len,a.a[a.len]);
        }
}

int main(){
        int b[]={3,1,2,3};
        int c[]={7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        f(*(av*)b);
        f(*(av*)c);
        return 0;
}
```

all good  by probably bug in alignment so size(3 and 7) is  right but value of a[] is not

UPD3 see throw gcc -g -c 2ndSRC.c &&objdump -d -M intel -S 2ndSRC.o

it just send only size (b[0] and c[0]) but not all array

Comment: Tip: Always compile with full warnings, and *handle them all*: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: 1. Get rid of the struct, use a simple array. 2. Declare and implement function `void pa(int arr[],int size)`. Note that it doesn't return anything, hence the return type is `void`. 3. From `main`, call `pa(value,sizeof(value)/sizeof(*value))`. 4. Declare function `pa` **outside and before** function `main`!!!

Comment: Deduplicator's suggestion assumes `gcc` (which is usually a pretty good assumption). `-Wall` is by far the most important flag of those three; the others are nowhere near as useful. You may also want to add `-std=c99` to choose the C99 standard.

Comment: @ooga: What's wrong with `-pedantic` if you don't want to rely on gcc extensions?

Comment: With variable size array do you mean a dynamically allocated array?

Comment: no.
variable size i mean i have int b[3], a[7] as local or global array 

and function func(some args, and argsArrayByvalue) . so that func can work as on b[3] as on a[7]

Comment: @mafso I didn't say there was anything wrong with it (although it's an assumption to think he doesn't want to rely on the very useful gnu extensions). I just said that the most important one was `-Wall`.

Comment: @qulinxao In C you it is not possible to "pass an array by value". What is the problem with passing a pointer to the first member of the array? You just have to pass the size of the array as second parameter.

Comment: @Étienne as u can see in 1st src we can pass array by value in C if we can say size of it on compile time

so Question . how write universal func on array of int where array of int passed by value .

Comment: @qulinxao In your first test you are passing a structure by value, not an array directly. See also this question about getting the size of an array (passed to a function): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c

Comment: Actually someone already answered one of your questions by telling you it is not possible to pass an array by value in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969095/how-to-send-array-by-value-to-function-in-c

Comment: pls @Étienne see throw gcc what code generate this:


    pa(\*(rec\*)value); 

 it copy sizeof(rec) byte from value to stack

my only problem that sizef of copy not in runtime but compile time

so if i can copy more than needed byte big rec is aproptiate solution

my current question is how copy as litle is pocible but get data by value, not  by reference

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic way to have arrays containing data of variable length in C is to use a buffer with a maximum size which is known at compile time, is that what you wanted?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 15
typedef struct {
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    size_t arr_len;
} rec_t;

void pa(rec_t rec){
    for(int z=0; z<rec.arr_len; z++){
        printf("array[%2d] is %d\n", z, rec.arr[z]);
    }

}

int main(void){
        rec_t rec ={
            .arr = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0},
            .arr_len = 10
        };
        pa(rec);
}
```

Comment: I find (*(rec)arraypointer) it get me sizeof rec chunk from *arraypointer.
But i dont know how get variable size chunk by value .