# Passing pointer to string, incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, string, pointers, arguments

So I'm sure this question is answered many times already but I am having trouble seeing how to fix my situation. I took a snippet of my program that contains my warning-generating code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

inputData(int size, char *storage[size])
{
    int iterator = -1;

    do {
        iterator++;
        *storage[iterator] = getchar();
    } while (*storage[iterator] != '\n' && iterator < size);
}

main()
{
    char name[30];

    inputData(30, name);
}
```

The warning message:

$ gcc text.c
text.c: In function ‘main’:
text.c:18:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘inputData’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] inputData(30, name); ^ text.c:4:1: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’ inputData(int size, char *storage[size])

EDIT:

Ok, so I managed to play around with some syntax and fixed my problem. I still wouldn;t mind hearing from somebody more knowledgeable than I why precisely this was needed. Here is what I changed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

inputData(int size, char *storage) // changed to point to the string itself 
{
    int iterator = -1;

    do {
        iterator++;
        storage[iterator] = getchar(); // changed from pointer to string
    } while (storage[iterator] != '\n'); // same as above
}

main()
{
    char name[30];

    inputData(30, name);

    printf("%s", name); // added for verification
}
```

Comment: Inside `inputData()`, code should have 3 reasons to stop: 1) `getchar()` returned `'\n'` 2) `getchar()` returned `EOF` 3) No more room.

Answer (score 2):

Array name converted to pointer to its first element when passed to a function. `name` will be converted to `&name[0]` (*pointer to `char`* type) which is the address of first element of array `name`. Therefore, second parameter of your function must be of *pointer to `char`* type.

`char *storage[size]` is equivalent to `char **storage` when declared as function parameter. Therefore, change `char *storage[size]` to `char *storage`.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array to a function, you can do it in 2 ways :
Consider the following program :-

```
int  main()
{
   int array[10];
   function_call(array); // an array is always passed by reference, i.e. a pointer   
   //code                // to base address of the array is passed.
   return 0;
}
```

Method 1:

```
void function_call(int array[])
{
  //code
}
```

Method 2:

```
void function_call(int *array)
{
  //code
}
```

The only difference in the two methods is the syntax, otherwise both are the same.
It is worth mentioning that in C language the arrays are not passed by value but by
reference.
You might find the following link useful : -

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774456/pass-an-array-to-a-function-by-value
```