# How to convert array function into pointer function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

So I understand the basics of Array functions, but I am having trouble converting this source code from an array function to a function using pointers.

```
void sortArray(int array[], int size)
{
  bool swap;
  int temp; 
  do
  {
    swap = false;
    for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
      {
        if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
        {
          temp = array[count];
          array[count] = array[count + 1];
          array[count + 1] = temp;
          swap = true;
        }
      }
    } while (swap);
}
```

Comment: `void sortArray(int* array, int size)`? Check out this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm).

Comment: That *is* a function using pointers. In function parameters, `T x[]` is equivalent to `T* x`.

Answer (score 0):

This function already can work with pointers.

Definition:

```
void sortArray(int array[], int size)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
void sortArray(int* array, int size)
```

Comment: just curious if your prototype is like `void sortArray(int array[], int size);` and you have a variable.. `int *arr = new int[size];` and you call the func `sortArray(arr,size);` will the array be passed by ref or copy

Comment: @Minato Look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774456/pass-an-array-to-a-function-by-value

Comment: By doing that I will change the parameters of the function, does that mean I must also chance the elements of the function (i.e from array[count] to *array[count]?

Comment: @ElSpiffy no.. you can use the pointer provided as a normal array

Comment: If that is true then why am I being asked to create a bubble sort using pointer algorithms? I mean, it makes sense that they are equivalent. But is there a difference from array bubble sort and pointer bubble sort?

Comment: @ElSpiffy Arrays are passed as base address between functions.. that said.. when you declare it like above it is expecting an address.. since array are contagious memory.. you just increment the base address to retrieve the next element..

Comment: @ElSpiffy, If you want to show, that you are using pointers, you can replace `array[i]` to `*(array + i)`, but it will not change the assembler code because both of these variants are totally equivalent.