# How to retain original values of an array after being called?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
  #include <iostream>

  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  void staticArrayInit(int[]);     

int main()
{
   int array2[3]={1,2,3};

   cout << "First call to each function:\n";
   staticArrayInit(array2);

   cout << "\n\nSecond call to each function:\n";
   staticArrayInit(array2);
   cout << endl;

   return 0;  

} 

  void staticArrayInit(int array2[])
{


static int array1[ 3 ];  

   cout << "\nValues on entering staticArrayInit:\n";

   for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
     cout << "array1[" << i << "] = " << array1[ i ] << "  ";

   cout << "\nValues on exiting staticArrayInit:\n";

    for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
      cout << "array1[" << j << "] = " 
           << ( array1[ j ] += 5 ) << "  ";

   cout << "\n\nValues on entering automaticArrayInit:\n";

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
      cout << "array2[" << i << "] = " << array2[ i ] << "  ";

   cout << "\nValues on exiting automaticArrayInit:\n";

   for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
      cout << "array2[" << j << "] = " 
           << (array2[ j ] += array1[j]) << "  ";

}
```

As you can see, `staticarrayinit` is gonna be called twice. After the first call, the original values of `array2` (1,2,3) will be modified and in the second call the values that will be displayed are the modified ones. How can I retain the original values of `array2` and display it in the second call of `staticArrayInit`?

Comment: Keep a back up before passing to function.

Comment: Try this mental excersize: substitute a simple variable, say `int x`, for your array. Everywhere you currently have an array, you just have an `int x`, and you would be passing a pointer to the `int x`, instead of an array. Now, answer your own question. You should be able to answer it easily. If not, it's time for you reread the last 2 or 3 chapters in your C++ book. But if you can answer this simplified question, then you should now be able to easily realize that the same exact answer that you came up for `int x` also applies to an array as well. Wonders never cease!

Comment: You are actually asking question how to pass array by value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774456/pass-an-array-to-a-function-by-value

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass array contents by value so to retain original values you need to maintain copy of original array as described in below code :

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;

  void staticArrayInit(int[]);     

int main()
{
   int array2[3]={1,2,3};

   cout << "First call to each function:\n";
   staticArrayInit(array2);

   cout << "\n\nSecond call to each function:\n";
   staticArrayInit(array2);
   cout << endl;

   return 0;  

} 

  void staticArrayInit(int array2[])
{


static int array1[ 3 ];  
int arraycopy[sizeof(array2)];
std::copy(array2,array2+3,arraycopy);
   cout << "\nValues on entering staticArrayInit:\n";

   for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
     cout << "array1[" << i << "] = " << array1[ i ] << "  ";

   cout << "\nValues on exiting staticArrayInit:\n";

    for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
      cout << "array1[" << j << "] = " 
           << ( array1[ j ] += 5 ) << "  ";

   cout << "\n\nValues on entering automaticArrayInit:\n";

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
      cout << "array2[" << i << "] = " << array2[ i ] << "  ";

   cout << "\nValues on exiting automaticArrayInit:\n";

   for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
      cout << "array2[" << j << "] = " 
           << (array2[ j ] += array1[j]) << "  ";
std::copy(arraycopy,arraycopy+3,array2);
}
```