# Are array passed in function argument treated as call by reference?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

An array as a function argument is treated as a pointer. So changing the value of the pointer will change the original value passed array. Am I correct or is the something is wrong in this?

Comment: Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. And the pointer to the first element is passed by value. *All* arguments are passed by value in C.

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567742/passing-an-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c/6567846

Comment: But since it is a pointer so any changes in the pointer should be reflected in the value that is passed?

Comment: If you modify the data that the pointer is pointing at, then yes that will stay. But changing the pointer itself, i.e. making it point somewhere else, will not work.

Answer (score 3):

In C language array passed as parameters to function are treated as pointers. The address of the 1st index element of the array is passed to the formal parameter(parameter declared in function prototype). If your function manipulates the elements of the array passed , then yes it will also reflect in the actual array. Therefore it is a Call by reference.

Comment: Then what if i don't want to change my original values and just and a copy of that array?

Comment: @chinmaykumar you can do this by using structure. Make a function which takes structure variable as a parameter. Then inside function definition declare another structure variable and make it assign to the formal parameter. Then return that function structure variable initialized above and print it accordingly.

Comment: Can u show me a simple program of this?

Comment: @chinmaykumar: You might like to have look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4774456/694576

Comment: @chinmaykumar 
struct myObj{
 int mark[3];
 }x;
// function declaration 
 struct myObj array(struct myObj formal){
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
  formal.mark[i]+=1;
 }
 return formal;
}
//main
 int main(){
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   scanf("%d",&x.mark[i]);
  }
 struct myObj b= array(x);
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   printf("%d",x.mark[i]);
  }
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   printf("\n%d",b.mark[i]);
  }

 return 0;
}