# What's wrong with 'template< unsigned N, unsigned M> int compare(char p1 [N], char p2 [M])'

Tags: c++, templates

while I came across this snippet in <<C++ Primer>>

```
template< unsigned N, unsigned M>
int compare(const char(&p1)[N], const char (&p2)[M]
{
    return strcmp(p1, p2);
}
compare("hi", "mom")
```

sure it worked very well
then i thought what if if remove `const` and `&` ?
so i wrote this

```
template< unsigned N, unsigned M>
int compare(char p1 [N], char p2 [M])
{
    return strcmp(p1, p2);
}
compare("hi", "mom")
```

but i got this error

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:34:12: error: no matching function for call to 'compare(const char [3], const char [4])'
   34 |     compare("hi", "mom");
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:27:5: note: candidate: 'template<unsigned int N, unsigned int M> int compare(char*, char*)'
   27 | int compare(char p1 [N], char p2 [M])
      |     ^~~~~~~
prog.cc:27:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:34:12: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'N'
   34 |     compare("hi", "mom");
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You might want to focus on one change at a time. That is, bring back the `const` and see what happens if you remove just the `&`.

Comment: I thied, it did't work either.  I Got error message like this```no matching function for call to 'compare(const char [3], const char [4]);  candidate: 'template<unsigned int N, unsigned int M> int compare(const char*, const char*)'```

Comment: You can't pass a C-style array by value, only by reference. And string literals specifically must always be passed by const reference.

Comment: @cirfe So you see my point? Bringing back the `const` gives you almost the same error message. The only difference is that `const` was brought into the signature of the candidate function, which is to be expected. **You have the same error if you keep `const`.** So why not strip away inconsequential details? Instead of *"what if [I] remove `const` and `&` ?"*, ask *"what if [I] remove `&` ?"*. The fewer differences between your working and not-working code, the fewer red herrings you'll have to sniff.

Comment: I found curious that the template `compare` function does not actually use `N` nor `M` template parameters. It should use them to optimize and secure against non-null terminated strings. Simply with `return memcmp(p1, p2, std::min(N, M));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither in C nor in C++ there exists a straight-forward manner to pass a C-style array by value (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774456/pass-an-array-to-a-function-by-value)). A C-style array - if not wrapped by a class or struct - is actually only passed as a **pointer**. This also leads to problems with template deduction as a [**pass by value decays to a simple pointer**](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) and therefore the compiler can't deduce the template argument. Therefore the common approach is to either pass it by `const` or non-`const` reference or to switch to an `std::array` if a copy is needed. **I don't think the second version of your template actually does what you want it to do**.

---

Your initial code

```
template <unsigned N, unsigned M>
int compare(char const (&p1)[N], char const (&p2)[M]) {
  return std::strcmp(p1, p2);
}
```

is [working fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tWOcawvbxcvbdz3M). [A reference to an array does not decay to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17753057/9938686): Therefore when calling the template with `compare("hi", "mom")` the compiler is able to deduce `N` to `3` and `M`to `4` (`+1` because it is null-terminated).

- As soon as you remove the constant but keep the reference

  ```
  template <unsigned N, unsigned M>
  int compare(char (&p1)[N], char (&p2)[M]) {
    return std::strcmp(p1, p2);
  }
  ```

  the [code will stop compiling](https://wandbox.org/permlink/anzdZOSSaF2Lxxoe) if called with something like `compare("hi", "mom")` as they are string literals, which are **constant lvalues**, and therefore can't be passed to non-constant references but it [would still work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pMfs35wx0aA7adYi) if the two variables are not string literals but instead regular variables.
- If you remove the reference keeping the constant

  ```
  template <unsigned N, unsigned M>
  int compare(char const p1[N], char const p2[M]) {
    return std::strcmp(p1, p2);
  }
  ```

  the [compiler will **not be able to deduct the template arguments `M` and `N`** anymore as the argument will decay to a pointer](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BxO1EZVEU7zdH14v). As soon as you tell it which version to use `compare<3,4>("hi", "mom");` or add two other arguments for the length of the arrays it will [compile fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BLvubeapLb5UUHyS) but be aware - you are actually **not creating a copy of the array but instead you are only using a constant pointer** which might seem unexpected.
- Now when removing both - `const` as well as the reference -

  ```
  template <unsigned N, unsigned M>
  int compare(char p1[N], char p2[M]) {
    return std::strcmp(p1, p2);
  }
  ```

  then [again the compiler won't be able to deduct the template arguments](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qFWfMep8HBXDxCcx). If you then tell it explicitly which template arguments to use it [might still compile depending on the compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hZf8oHbo7eDUETP5) (GCC for example will issue a warning but in case you activate [`-pedantic-errors` the program will terminate with an error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PJbIzgBVwlmZDwD9)). So to comply with the C++ standard you [should not give it any string literals or temporary values as input arguments as well](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VWqPDJ57hKvUbqdF). Again this behaves now contrary to what you might expect: **Modifying the values of `p1` and `p2` inside your function will actually change the ones inside your calling function!** Therefore I would not advise you to use this syntax at all - it is **very misleading**.

---

There area a couple of options for avoiding this mess altogether:

- You could pass the array by reference and then create your local copy manually.
- You could wrap it with a struct. This will automatically create a copy of the wrapped C-style array.
- You could use an `std::array<char,N>` instead which can be passed by value like a regular variable. When using it with `std::strcmp` - like in your case - you would though actually have to copy the data into another C-style array though.
- You could pass an `std::string` as input argument and [only then convert it to a `char` array for `std::strcmp`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VWqPDJ57hKvUbqdF)

  ```
  int compare(std::string const& p1, std::string const& p2) {
    return std::strcmp(p1.c_str(), p2.c_str());
  }
  ```

  or [use the `std::string` comparison operator instead](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2TIyqkwMEVPRlynU) as well

  ```
  int compare(std::string const& p1, std::string const& p2) {
    return (p1 == p2);
  }
  ```

  This allows you to get rid of the template completely.

Comment: String literals are lvalues, aka not temporaries. They can't be passed to non-const pointers/references simply because they're const.

Comment: @2b-t You're welcome. I suggest fixing the answer to not confuse future readers.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am already working on it, thanks!

Comment: @JaMiT As soon as you add the template arguments it then it will [issue a warning `warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/scQUcek3vEZJLATD) and with [`-pedantic-erros` this will be an error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PJbIzgBVwlmZDwD9).

Comment: @JaMiT I am not sure if I understand what you are criticising. The OP asked for why this is not working and I gradually changed the code from his/her first version to his/her second version pointing out what the problems are and why you should actually pass it by reference. I added now a brief remark on C-style arrays and that it is in fact only a pointer as well as decay to pointers for arrays if passed by value which is the reason why the compiler can't deduct it. Let me know if that still is not a sufficient answer to this question in your opinion.

Comment: `std::array` has a `data()` function so there is no need to copy the data to compare it (unless it is not '\0' terminated).